# How to pass multiple key and their HTML tag attributes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `a-tag` looking like this

```
<a href={ item.htmlReportUrl } target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
{item.htmlReportText}</a>
```

which gets it's values for the `href` and the `linktext` from this

```
row.htmlReportUrl = res.db[key].htmlReport
row.htmlReportText = 'HTML Report'
```

My plan was now to in addtion pass

```
target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
```

in the same way. These attributes needs to be set just sometimes. But doing something like this

```
<a href={ item.finalUrl } { item.htmlReportAttributes }
```

isn't working.

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

I guess it's added to the href? How can I pass multiple html attributes at once?

Comment: You may be forgetting spread operator "...", This '...' is syntax `<a href={ item.finalUrl } { ...item.htmlReportAttributes }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
item.htmlReportAttributes["target"] = "_blank";
item.htmlReportAttributes["rel"] = "noopener noreferrer";
<a href={ item.finalUrl } { ...item.htmlReportAttributes } >{item.htmlReportText}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define attribute like this

```
let customAttr= {'target': '_blank','rel':'noopener noreferrer'}
```

then pass in html tag as below:

```
<a href={item.finalUrl} {...customAttr} >Link title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking state for the flag whether you want to use those extra attributes then you could try:

```
<a href={ item.finalUrl } target={this.state.addExtraAttributes == true ? "_blank" : ""} rel={this.state.addExtraAttributes == true ? "noopener noreferre" : ""} >
```